# Running login operation 1/50 or 1/100 ratio of the total request in jmeter

Tags: testing, jmeter

I am running some tests on JMeter. I am testing a web application and its functionality for example login, homepage, product catalogue. So I have a test script and I am using the ultimate thread group for the users. But I would like to run the login request only once or twice on every 100 requests. I know I can use if controller for that and I tried few solutions but did not work. So I would like to know how I can run requests properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're supposed to share your "few solutions", otherwise it sounds like you're asking us to solve your problem.

If you want to run a Sampler 1 time per 100 iterations you can use the following [__jexl3() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) as the If Controller's condition:

```
${__jexl3(${__jm__jp@gc - Ultimate Thread Group__idx} % 100  == 0,)}
```

If you changed the Ultimate Thread Group label from default `jp@gc - Ultimate Thread Group` - you will need to change it in the function as well.

More information: [6 Tips for JMeter If Controller Usage](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage)

P.S. In majority if cases [Throughput Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) is much easier to use

Comment: Hi Dmitri, Thanks for your solution. It works. So I ran the test with 20 thread  and hold the load for 20 sec. and the login request was executed for 20 times. But the the total request was performed on the server was 418. But what i want do is run the login request once or twice per 100 request not thread. So for example if the total request performed was 2000 then login request should be performed 20 or 40 times. I don't know if I explained it to you properly. Please give me your suggestion on that. thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use [Once Only Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller) to run a request only once per thread/user
2. You can use [Throughput Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) to run requests by the percentage of total execution or count
3. You can use [Random Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Random_Controller) to randomly pick one item from the child requests
4. You can use [If Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) with execution count check

```
${__groovy(vars.get("loginCount").toInteger() <=4  && (new Random()).nextBoolean() )}
```

You will have to set the `loginCount` variable  for successful logins

```
int loginCount = vars.get("loginCount").toInteger().next()
vars.put("loginCount", loginCount.toString())
```

You need to ensure the login request is executed in the first iteration/loop. For the following iterations, you can randomly pick the login request using other appropriate logic controllers.

Also you can combine them to simulate complex combinations.